# Android Device Administrator intent doesn't shows up (REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN)

Tags: android, device-admin

I'm developing an application which uses Device Administrator permissions to pin the screen.

After some research i've found a solution: with the ADB i can manually set up my App as a Device Administrator.

The other solution would be using NFC which is not embedded in my device.

Now I'd like to use a more simple way of provide Admin permission, so I've figure out that there is an intent for asking the user to set it up.

Here's my code, in which i start the intent, inside a Button click:

`final ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
            mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);`

```
  Privilegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin);
                            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                                    "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Splash.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here's AdminReceiver Class:

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Device Admin Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return "Device Admin Warning";
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLockTaskModeEntering(Context context, Intent intent, String pkg) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin Kios Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLockTaskModeExiting(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin Kios Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And my XML:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Everything works fine with the ADB method, but if i try to use the intent, it just pass through it without displaying nothing.

In "onActivityResult" i get 0 as result code.

I restored factory data before any attempt.

Thanks.